# Updated Maven Failed, How to fix it?

Tags: spring, maven

I have added some dependencies in file pom.xml

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core
>   jackson-core   2.7.3
>    
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core
>   jackson-databind   2.7.3
>    
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core
>   jackson-annotations
>   2.7.3

But When I execute a command  **mvn eclipse:eclipse** to update maven dependencies, it shows a warning message:

> Downloading:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jac
>   kson-core/2.7.3/jackson-core-2.7.3.pom [WARNING] Failed to create
>   parent directories for tracking file C:\Program Files 
>   (x86)\apache-maven-3.3.9\REPO\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.7.3\jac
>   kson-core-2.7.3.pom.lastUpdated Downloading:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jac
>   kson-databind/2.7.3/jackson-databind-2.7.3.pom [WARNING] Failed to
>   create parent directories for tracking file C:\Program Files 
>   (x86)\apache-maven-3.3.9\REPO\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.7.3
>   \jackson-databind-2.7.3.pom.lastUpdated Downloading:
>   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jac
>   kson-annotations/2.7.3/jackson-annotations-2.7.3.pom [WARNING] Failed
>   to create parent directories for tracking file C:\Program Files 
>   (x86)\apache-maven-3.3.9\REPO\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.
>   7.3\jackson-annotations-2.7.3.pom.lastUpdated [INFO] File D:\PROJECTSPRING\springMOTHER-service.project already exists.
>          Additional settings will be preserved, run mvn eclipse:clean if you want old settings to be removed.

This doesn't updated the dependencies mentioned in my POM.xml, please let me know ?

Here file pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>edu.java.spring.service</groupId>
  <artifactId>springDAT-service</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>springDAT-service Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <version>10.12.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>



    <dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>springMOTHER-service</finalName>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    <argLine>-Xmx2524m</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-XDignore.symbol.file</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.3.0.M1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArgs>-Xmx1048m -Xms536m
                        -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m</jvmArgs>
                    <reload>manual</reload>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>lib</name>
                            <value>${basedir}/target/spring-mvc/WEB-INF/lib</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>3</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <connectors>
                        <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                            <port>8080</port>
                            <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                        </connector>
                    </connectors>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <webXml>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <classesDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</classesDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should never put your local repository into `C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.3.9\REPO\`...

First don't put it into `C:\Programm Files...` cause this is usually forbidden by Windows...

Furthermore don't put a repository under the Maven installation. This should be kept into `C:/Users/username/.m2/repository` as the default or if you change this by changing the settings.xml put it somewhere like `C:\mvn-repo`...

Apart from that above you shouldn't use `mvn eclipse:eclipse` anymore better use the M2E Support in Eclipse and import the appropriate project into Eclipse...

Comment: you can let me know why some dependency before, i can update but some dependency of jackson can't update maven ???

Comment: i have change local repository with your way, everything run ok, thank you more :)))